# docker run results in "unable to find image" if linked container not found

Tags: docker

I'm getting possibly incorrect behavior and a bad error message if I run an image if a linked container is not found:

```
# this works:
> docker run --rm -d --name natsserver nats
> docker run --rm -it --name hello-world --link natsserver hello-world

# now stop natsserver again...
> docker stop natsserver
```

When I run hello-world again with the same command, I don't understand the first part of the error handling - why does docker try to pull?

```
> docker run --rm -it --name hello-world --link natsserver hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
Digest: sha256:b8ba256769a0ac28dd126d584e0a2011cd2877f3f76e093a7ae560f2a5301c00
Status: Image is up to date for hello-world:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: could not get container for natsserver: No such container: natsserver.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

And things get even worse if I try to run an image I have built locally:

```
> docker build -t nats-logger .
[...]
Successfully tagged nats-logger:latest

> docker run --rm -it --name nats-logger --link=natsserver nats-logger
Unable to find image 'nats-logger:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for nats-logger, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So my questions are:

a) Is docker **allowed** to try to pull in this case, or is this a bad behavior?

b) Is this really a bad error message, or did I miss something?

P.S.: I'm running Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc on Windows 10.

Comment: the error `docker: Error response from daemon: could not get container for natsserver: No such container: natsserver.` say it all the container should be running

Answer (score 1):

> Is docker allowed to try to pull in this case

Docker will pull image if it is not available on the machine.

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally

This warning message is not due to linking, it is because `hello-world:latest` is not exist in your system local images. so whe run `docker run` it will look on local then will pull from remote if not exist.

[image]

Now First thing, Better to use docker-compose instead of Legacy container links.

You can not link the container if it's not running. verify the container `natsserver` using `docker ps` and then if it is running then you can link.

```
docker run --rm -it --name hello-world --link natsserver:my_natserver_host hello-world
```

Once up you can then check the linking.

```
docker inspect hello-world | grep -A 1 Links
```

**Legacy container links**

> Warning: The `--link flag` is a legacy feature of Docker. It may
>   eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using
>   it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate
>   communication between two containers instead of using `--link`. One
>   feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with
>   `--link` is sharing environment variables between containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment
>   variables between containers in a more controlled way.

Answer (score 0):

- simply try "docker login".
- check if your image name is exist in docker hub
- and check correct docker build command -> `docker build -t image-name .`
- review the correctness of Docker file script